# there is no effect when setting line height for button within svg

Tags: html, css

I found these buttons like [this screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msbUZ.png) in the website [zhihu](https://www.zhihu.com/).

When I try to make my version of these buttons, mine is like [this screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvu1l.png).

The css line-height can not make any effect to the button without text, but line-height is useful for the button within text.That is strange. Both of the buttons is within svg tag.

my html code:

```
<body>
<div class="RichContent is-collapsed">
    <div class="ContentItem-actions">
        <span>
            <button class="Button VoteButton VoteButton--down" aria-label="反对"
                type="button">
                <svg viewBox="0 0 20 18"
                    class="Icon VoteButton-downIcon Icon--triangle" width="9"
                    height="16" aria-hidden="true" style="height: 16px; width: 9px;">
                <title>a</title>
                <g> <path
                    d="M0 15.243c0-.326.088-.533.236-.896l7.98-13.204C8.57.57 9.086 0 10 0s1.43.57 1.784 1.143l7.98 13.204c.15.363.236.57.236.896 0 1.386-.875 1.9-1.955 1.9H1.955c-1.08 0-1.955-.517-1.955-1.9z"></path></g></svg>

            </button>
            <button class="Button VoteButton VoteButton--down" aria-label="反对"
                type="button">
                <svg viewBox="0 0 20 18"
                    class="Icon VoteButton-downIcon Icon--triangle" width="9"
                    height="16" aria-hidden="true" style="height: 16px; width: 9px;">
                <title></title>
                <g> <path
                    d="M0 15.243c0-.326.088-.533.236-.896l7.98-13.204C8.57.57 9.086 0 10 0s1.43.57 1.784 1.143l7.98 13.204c.15.363.236.57.236.896 0 1.386-.875 1.9-1.955 1.9H1.955c-1.08 0-1.955-.517-1.955-1.9z"></path></g></svg>
                59
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

my css code:

```
<style type="text/css">
button {
    padding: 0;
    font: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}

.Button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 16px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 32px;
    color: #8590a6;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: none;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 3px;
    white-space-collapsing: discard;
}

.VoteButton {
    padding: 0 10px;
    color: #0084ff;
    background: rgba(0, 132, 255, .1);
    border-color: transparent;
}

.VoteButton--down {
    margin-left: 4px;
}

.Icon {
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    fill: currentColor;
}

.VoteButton-downIcon, .VoteButton-upIcon {
    fill: currentColor;
}

.VoteButton-downIcon {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.ContentItem-actions {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 0 -20px -10px;
    color: #646464;
    background: #fff;
    clear: both;
}

.RichContent {
    line-height: 1.67;
}
```

"line-height: 32px;" can't work!

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve because on code pen your codeis working perfectly, the buttons are both the same size and like the website where you took it from https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zWQwXv

Comment: Oh, my god. That is weird. My screen shots are true and my code is the same as yours in codepen. And my web browser is chrome 64.0.3282.119

Comment: Is the code pen working for you ?

Comment: The code pen works for me and i see the buttons are both the same size. I am finding the reason why. thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, happy coding buddy

Comment: I am still working on it. I find that the code works fine in codepen and jsfiddle. But when i save it as html file and open it in browser, the two buttons are not in the same size. That is interesting.

Comment: That's weird because it's woring perfectly on my browser, Chrome Version 65.0.3325.181 Maybe you should upgrade your version of chrome

Answer (score 2):

I am the quizzer of this question.

Finally, I found the solution. Thanks for the help of Lucas and Joe.

When the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration of the web page is for HTML4 like `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`, the css "line-height" doesn't work for the button which only has svg content but doesn't have any text content.

But if we change the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration form HTML4 version to HTML5 version, like `<!DOCTYPE html>`, the "line-height" works for both of the buttons, no matter the button has text content or not.

And yes, the HTML5 version of the  declaration is just like `<!DOCTYPE html>`, it's very concise. But obviously, it is not suitable for the old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any `div` in your HTML code that is class named

> Button

I think css code might look like this:

```
.RichContent is-collapsed .ContentItem-actions button {
/* Your code here */
}
```

Hope this helps.

Best regards, Joe.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this question. But I do have a class named "Button" in my code: `<button class="Button VoteButton VoteButton--down" aria-label="反对"
                type="button">`

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I probably didn't see that. Then I have a second solution. Try to set the height instead of line-height (or width I don't know what is what because I am from the Czech Republic.).